# Determine if a FirefoxProfile is accepting untrusted certificates or not

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

How can you check if a Firefox profile is accepting untrusted certificates?

I know you can set it true/false with code like this:

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(false);
```

But how can you determine what a `FirefoxProfile` has it set to?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#setAcceptUntrustedCertificates-boolean-) :

> **public void setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(boolean acceptUntrustedSsl)**
>
> Sets whether Firefox should accept SSL certificates which have
>   expired, signed by an unknown authority or are generally untrusted.
>   This is set to ***true by default***.

So unless you change it to false, its already true and by the code one should know when using your controls has the flag been changed.

Comment: Yeah that is true, I was just wondering if there was a way to check, since I was writing some unit tests for a method that sets the setting to off. Thanks